# asp.net cache sharing between main site add its applications/virtual directories (using iis 7.5)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, shared-cache

My solution contains 4 projects: Core, Data (libraries), Admin, Client (MVC 3 sites).

Admin and Client communicate with DB with Data project's repositories.

I want to cache data in Data project using HttpContext.Current.Cache for both Admin and Client and invalidate cached data after updates that can appear both in Admin and Client.

How should I configure sites, applications or virtual directories and app pools to have the same cache in Client and Admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't share the standard ASP.NET cache across applications. However, you can use tools like [memchached](http://memcached.org/) or [Velocity by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx).